# How to move existing Terraform resources from single items to set?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have an SQL db module with single databases like this:

```json
resource "google_sql_database" "projects" {
  name     = "projects"
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.database.name
}

resource "google_sql_database" "markdown" {
  name     = "markdown"
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.database.name
}
```

I'd like to switch to set of variables instead:

```json
variable "databases" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["projects", "markdown"]
}

resource "google_sql_database" "database" {
  for_each = toset(var.databases)
  name     = each.key
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.database.name
}
```

And when I do `terraform apply` the CLI wants to recreate everything:

```bash
# module.sql.google_sql_database.database["markdown"] will be created
+ resource "google_sql_database" "database" {
...
...

# module.sql.google_sql_database.markdown will be destroyed
- resource "google_sql_database" "markdown" {
...
...
```

How to avoid that and mirror the existing resources to new config?

Answer (score 1):

You either need to run `terraform state mv` [command](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/state/mv) for each resource, or add `moved` [blocks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/refactoring) to your Terraform code.

Comment: Thanks. I will play with that